# jQuery prettyPhoto - Setting a max height and width for the lightbox

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto, css

I have installed the Pretty Photo jQuery plugin but I need to set a min and max height and width of the lightbox and can't seem to get it working.

I've tried changing the `prettyPhoto.css` file and no luck, I tried looking at the `prettyPhoto.js` file and can't work out how the dimensions are actually set!?

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
        default_width: 500,
        default_height: 344,
        horizontal_padding: 20
      });
    });
```

[fixed window-size in prettyphoto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469214/fixed-window-size-in-prettyphoto)

Answer (score 2):

Look for div.pp_pic_holder in PrettyPhoto.css file `/css/prettyPhoto.css`
and apply required width with `!important`
Ex. `width: 825px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/2013/is-there-a-way-to-define-minimum-width/p1) is a possible workaround for your problem. This is what helped me the most.