# How to make large the size of PrettyPhoto on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, prettyphoto

I want to make the picture width & height more larger example fullwidth. 
but i dont know how to do it in prettyphoto

My code for prettyphoto is

```
/*-- PRETTY PHOTO --*/
$("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
social_tools: false
/*-- PRETTY PHOTO END --*/
```

Comment: Please do not confuse "Java" and "Javascript". These two are as unrelated as Austria and Australia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery prettyPhoto - Setting a max height and width for the lightbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647291/jquery-prettyphoto-setting-a-max-height-and-width-for-the-lightbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    allow_resize: true, /* Resize the photos bigger than viewport. true/false */
    default_width: 500,
    default_height: 344,
    horizontal_padding: 20
});
```

Comment: Thank you ..  
and how about to change the  preview of prettyphoto image
example i want it fullwidth ?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647291/jquery-prettyphoto-setting-a-max-height-and-width-for-the-lightbox